# PL/SQL loop to delete records

Tags: loops, plsql

For most people this will be a simple question but I can't find the answer and our developers won't help with sql. I'm a total amateur.

I have a table called User_accounts with 2 fields:  UserID, Value.  There are 500k records.  UserID is unique for all records.

I have a temp table with the same 2 fields with approx 30k records.  Also, no duplicate UserID's.

For every record on the temp table, I want to delete the corresponding record from User_accounts.

I "could" run a simple delete statement 30k times.  It would take forever to run.  There must be a really simple query that would go through the temp table.  Will you help me?

Comment: You don't need a cursor for this operation, and you don't need to run a simple delete statement more than once. `DELETE FROM User_Accounts WHERE UserID in (SELECT UserID FROM Temp)`. You could also just use `WHERE EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

Your delete statement can delete all the selected IDs in one go, given a suitable where clause, which can refer to another table, e.g.:

```
delete user_accounts u
where exists (
  select null
  from   temp_table t
  where  t.userid = u.userid
  );
```